# Adding element to list with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, foreach

In the groupBox control, there are four checkBox element and their tags' names are 1, 2, 3, 4. checkBox1, checkBox3 and checkBox4 are selected. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want to add selected checkbox items' tag to List item.
I tried like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> filter = new List<int>();

    var add_tags = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => cb.Checked).ForEach(cbx => filter.Add(Convert.ToInt32(cbx.Tag)));

}
```

But it returns error and I don't understand the error.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: A bit complicated, but you cannot assign a ForEach, you are storing yet to the filter, you don't need the add_tags var.

Comment: @Pranay Rana, Yes absolutely. I want to click thick for the first time. But site said that you can not accept in 5 minutes. Later, I forgot. Sorry and thank you very much again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all selected checkboxes tags in a list then you can do like this, right now you are not using function other than `Select`

```
 List<int> filter = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                      .Where(cb => cb.Checked)
                     .Select(cbx => Convert.ToInt32(cbx.Tag))
                     .ToList();
```

assuming that all tags are int.

---

if you want to avoid any error related parsing you can try like this

```
 List<int> filter = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                             .Where(cb => cb.Checked)
                             .Select(cbx => parseTag(cbx.Tag.toString()))
                             .ToList();

private int parseTag(string tag) 
{   
  int num;   
  if (!Int32.TryParse(tag, out num)) 
  {
    num = int.MaxValue; // or int.MinValue - however it should show up in sort   
  }
  return num; 
}
```

Comment: `Select` should start with cap. letter

Comment: select -> Select

Comment: @Marc - thanks too many typos updated...effect of working with typescript.. thanks again

Comment: @MarkBenovsky - thanks too many typos updated...effect of working with typescript.. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code a little bit, this must work:

```
groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(cb => 
cb.Checked).ToList().ForEach(cbx => filter.Add(Convert.ToInt32(cbx.Tag)));
```

don't assign it to a variable as `ForEach` (the last called method in the expression chain) doesn't return a value, it just does something (`Action`) and you already adding to the `filter` list.